# Jquery scroller needs to move one content downward at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery scroller which moves one content upward at a time. But when we click on upward link it moves multiple content smoothly downwards.I want this move downward link also move one content down at a time. I have edited the jquery script bt failed to scroll down one by one.

This is the jquery scroller script i have edited

```
(function($){ 
window.onload=function(){ 
    $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:1, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:1, 
        scrollSpeed:300, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the jsfiddle of my jqueryscroller i have edited.Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/VT4L6/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still haven't been able to work out the answer: you have built in the step option and updated the animation to take into account the step to calculate the distance to be moved, but the condition which is used to determine whether the end has been reached has not been updated with the step option.

You can overcome this by changing the if condition on the next button

```
if(diffY>=$this.height()*options.step){...}
```

and the prev button

```
if(posY+$this.height()*options.step<=0){...}
```

here's the link to the full working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fN3k9/

Comment: I have copied and overwrite the script with the new script on your jsfiddle but its not working..please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, when you go to my jsfiddle and do not change anything in there, it already works like you intended it to, no? In my jsfiddle the scroller always moves just one section down and up. Please clarify.